# source /.bash_profile command not working

Tags: bash, terminal, alias, macos-catalina

I am trying to refresh my aliases on my Mac (OS Catalina 10.15.6) after defining new aliases in my .bash_profile file with the command:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

But terminal keeps giving this error message:`-bash: s: command not found`

This is confusing because for the longest time this command worked. I even had it included in my .bash_profile file as an alias, where it worked fine.

I'm aware the problem could have to do it with an error in my PATH but I've never made any edits to my PATH so have no idea what the issue could be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So enter the command `s`'s full path (doing `type s` might give an answer).

Comment: It sounds like there's a bad line _in_ the .bash_profile itself, trying to run the command `s`.

Comment: Can you please be much more specific about the problem you're seeing? You say it "keeps giving this error message", but I can't tell if that means 1. "My alias is named `s` and I get this message every time I run `s`", or 2. "I get this error as a response to the `source` command", or 3. "I get this message for every command I run" or 4. "This message keeps printing in an infinite loop"

Comment: Error aside, aliases should be defined in `.bashrc`, not `.bash_profile` (and specific to macOS, you should source your `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`).

Comment: @MarkReed You were right! There was an `"s"` accidentally typed in my .bash_profile. Thanks!

Comment: @thatotherguy Sorry, should have been more clear.  To clarify, I meant I keep getting -`bash: s: command not found` in response to inputting the command `"source ~/.bash_profile"`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, will probably make that switch then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct would be to check both ~/.bashrc, and /etc/bashrc if it exists.  That is where I customarily define aliases, and it looks to me as though a bad alias ***may*** be your problem.

I'm not saying it was the one you made, although it might be.  Just go through your rc and profile files and look for any aliases which might in any way clash with source.

Comment: Thanks! Was definitely a case of it being a bad alias on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `source` command is working just fine and the problem is a bad line in the ~/.bash_profile itself that looks like it's trying to run a command named `s`. I would look in there for the problem.

It might help to run it with xtrace on via `bash -x ~/.bash_profile` – running it in a separate process like that won't have any of the presumably-desired side effects of `source`ing it in your current shell, but you can see what it's trying to do so that you can fix it.

(You can also just `set -x` before the `source` and get both xtrace and running in the current shell; just be sure to `set +x` afterwards or your shell session will be full of debug output.)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, looks like that was exactly the issue. There was an accidentally typed `s` in ~/.bash_profile. Works now! But still confused as to why `s` would cause an issue when trying to run `source` command?

Comment: `source $filename` (also spelled `. $filename`) means "run all the commands in `$filename` as if I typed them". So if the file has a line that starts with s, you get the same result you'd get if you typed a line starting with s at the command line - which, unless you have defined or installed a command by that name, is the error message you saw.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Appreciate the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

I used `source <(helm completion zsh)` instead of `source <(helm completion bash)` and it worked!

First I set `source <(helm completion bash)` in my `bash_profile` and it showed the following error `/dev/fd/12:type:332: bad option: -t` .

Then I replaced it with `source <(helm completion zsh)` and it's working properly